# Android: Get View Location on Screen after View is scaled?

Tags: java, android, view

So my problem is that I need the position of the view relative to the screen after its scaled using the ScaleAnimation class. The getLocationOnScreen function is returning the same position before and after the scale animation. What it looks like its getting is the unscaled views position. Would the ScaleAnimation class not scale the old view but create a new one? If that's the case how could you get the pointer of the new view?

Here's the code

```
public void scaleView(final View v, float startScale, float endScale) {
    Animation anim = new ScaleAnimation(
            startScale, endScale, // Start and end values for the X axis scaling
            startScale, endScale, // Start and end values for the Y axis scaling
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0f, // Pivot point of X scaling
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f); // Pivot point of Y scaling
    anim.setFillAfter(true); // Needed to keep the result of the animation
    anim.setFillBefore(false);
    anim.setFillEnabled(true);
    anim.setDuration(500);
    anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            int [] location = new int[2];
            v.getLocationOnScreen(location);
            Log.e("ee","x:"+String.valueOf(location[0]));
            Log.e("ee","y:"+String.valueOf(location[1]));
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            int [] location = new int[2];
            v.getLocationOnScreen(location);
            Log.e("ee","x:"+String.valueOf(location[0]));
            Log.e("ee","y:"+String.valueOf(location[1]));
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
    v.startAnimation(anim);
}
```