# Calling canvas.scale() doesn't scale the click listener area of the views

Tags: android, kotlin, canvas, onclick

I have a bunch of Buttons in a LinearLayout. In the LinearLayout, I override onDraw() to call canvas.scale(scale, scale) where scale is some number. The buttons in the LinearLayout scales visually but the click area doesn't move and scale with the visual representation. In other words, the click area registers in the original position after scaling

Here is a demo where a slider is used to scale the canvas. After scaling, you can see the button shows it's clicked animation only when clicked in the original position

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
            android:id="@+id/mySlider"
            android:valueFrom=".5"
            android:valueTo="3"
            android:value="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <com.dgnt.playground.MyLinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/myContainer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="My Testing String Is A long one My Testing String Is A long one" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="My Testing String Is A long one My Testing String Is A long one" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="My Testing String Is A long one My Testing String Is A long one" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="My Testing String Is A long one My Testing String Is A long one" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="My Testing String Is A long one My Testing String Is A long one" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="My Testing String Is A long one My Testing String Is A long one" />



        </com.dgnt.playground.MyLinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Custom LinearLayout

```
class MyLinearLayout : LinearLayout {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyle
    )

    init {
        setWillNotDraw(false)
    }

    private var scale: Float = 1.0f;

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        canvas.scale(scale, scale)
    }

    fun setScale(value: Float) {
        scale = value
        invalidate()
        requestLayout()
    }

}
```

Main Activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater).apply {
            setContentView(root)

            mySlider.addOnChangeListener { slider, value, fromUser ->

                myContainer.setScale(value)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried instead overriding dispatchTouchEvent to figure out if the touch coordinates of the user intercepts the view but it seems like view.getLocationOnScreen() doesn't take into consideration the scale of the canvas either as evidenced by this question [Android: Get View Location on Screen after View is scaled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43428935/android-get-view-location-on-screen-after-view-is-scaled)

What can I do so that the click/touch registers exactly where the view is before and after scaling the canvas?

Comment: Yeah, what you're doing will never work.  The on screen drawing of a view via canvas has nothing to do with the touch area-  those are set by the view's location (and their onTouchEvent).  Scaling up the drawing does not change the size of the views, and would not change the view bounds. I'm surprised it worked at all, and would not really expect it to-  you're basically hoping that the Canvas used to draw the container is then used to draw children after the fact.  It doesn't need to be, and in fact I'm surprised that it does.

Comment: A more correct way to implement this would be to override onLayout to give the views a larger amount of area.  Of course that will only increase the view bounds, not scale the contents.  If you want to do that, I'd suggest subclassing button to scaling button and having it scale itself.  The fact that what you did even kind of works is depending on an implementation detail at best-  there's no reason to expect the scale of a canvas being used to draw the parent would still be there when drawing the child.  At worse its an active bug in Android.

Comment: @GabeSechan it literally worked with the accepted answer. Not sure what you're talking about

Comment: It shouldn't.  You're relying on implementation details that are not assured to work on all versions of Android and could break even in a point release.  This isn't even close to how you should be doing it.  The fact you're overriding dispatchTouchEvent is a big red flag-  rather than using Android as its supposed to be, you're overriding how touches interact with children.  It may work for a limited usecase, but it would cause problems for anything else.  THis is a horrible, buggy, and bad implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to fix this is to scale your touch events, I've done this in a custom view I created that has scaling and panning.

In your `MyLinearLayout` override `dispatchTouchEvent`

Create a `Matrix` that applies the scale factor then transform the `MotionEvent` with the scale Matrix before called the original `dispatchTouchEvent`

sorry in Java but something like (a bit from memory and not exactly how I did it as that had some more complicated use cases for panning and different pans for different parts of the screen)

```java
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

   Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
   Matrix mappingMatrix = new Matrix();

   matrix.setScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
   // From memory the Matrix for the transform has to be inverted
   matrix.invert(mappingMatrix);

   // Copy motion event because I seem to remember you cannot change the original motion event
   MotionEvent transformEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(ev);
   transformEvent.transform(mappingMatrix);

   // call parent class so this processes the modified event as normal
   boolean returnVal = super.dispatchTouchEvent(transformEvent);

   // Tidy up the copied motion event to not leak memory
   transformEvent.recycle();

   return returnVal;

}
```

Comment: Java is better than nothing. Will try this out later. Thanks

Comment: hey @Andrew, this worked as expected. thanks. My actual project also includes panning. how would I handle that as well if you dont mind answering. thanks

Comment: That depends on how you are doing pan, I just use translate on the matrix on the canvas to achieve it, therefore just  `matrix.postTranslate(panX, panY);` to map the touch events as well.